# Is Crystal Reports not available for VS 2022 preview?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I was using Crystal Reports in VS 2019 but I downloaded VS 2022. Is Crystal Reports not available for VS 2022 preview?

Comment: VS 2022 is a preview, non-production product atm. Don't expect anything to be compatible at this stage. CR for VS says it's compatible up to 2019 in their description.

Comment: This question should be archived because VS 2022 is no longer in preview. It was released on November 8, 2021

Answer (score 1):

Crystal report is now available for VS2022.
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

You can download from below URL also.
https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information from the links provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 is no more in preview mode, its final version has already been released.

For crystal report integration for VS 2022, here is the response from SAP. We need to wait for SP32.

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13463389/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2022-preview.html